# How to view HTML data associated with a QWebPage

Tags: qt4, qwebpage

I wrote a program that uses a QWebPage to retrieve websites. Is there a way to get the data associated with the web page, like HTML, CSS, and Javascript? Similar to view-source in firefox.

There seem to be a couple options. One way is to make a QNetworkReply proxy and try copying the data, but this seems prone to bugs. Another way is to interact with the cache, but this seems unpredictable. Any other ways possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've settled on using a [QNetworkReply Proxy](http://gitorious.org/qtwebkit/performance/blobs/master/host-tools/mirror/main.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

Probably over the `mainFrame()` member function to get a QWebFrame and then maybe over the `html()` function. I've never done this before, but seems to be the way to go. If you need the DOM of the document there is a `QWebElement documentElement () const` that gets you most of the needed attributes.

Comment: This might work for HTML, but I don't see a way to get other resources, like javascript, css, and images. I've settled on using a [QNetworkReply Proxy](http://gitorious.org/qtwebkit/performance/blobs/master/host-tools/mirror/main.cpp).